# How to subtract values from text field to apply discount from total?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code

What i am trying to do is to subtract from total value to give discount.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gettotal(){
var arr = document.getElementsByName('feetype');
var discount = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('discount').value);
var tot=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if( parseFloat(arr[i].value))
        tot +=  parseFloat(arr[i].value);
        tot = tot - discount;
 }

document.getElementById('recieveable').value = tot;
}

</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dr7mi.png)

Comment: Add Html for those elements that are using in the javascript

Comment: From the screen shot, discount seems to be applied to the sum of all of the fees.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is wrong `var discount = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('discount').value);`

`document.getElementsByName` returns `array of element` but here you are expecting a `single element`. Therefore you should user `document.getElementById` instead OR you can use what you are using with array `index`.

Change it to

`var discount = parseInt(document.getElementById('discount').value);`

OR

`var discount = parseInt(document.getElementsByName('discount')[0].value);`

if you've only one discount field.